# How do I view the parameters of currently running procs in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to troubleshoot an issue that is popping up on our new SQL Server. While viewing the running processes (`sp_who2`) I can't tell what parameters a proc was started with.

I can find the name of the proc using: `DBCC INPUTBUFFER (spid)`

I can even find some additional info, but I can't see a way to show the parameters.

(http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/sql-server-%E2%80%93-get-last-running-query-based-on-spid/)

I know I can see the parameters if I do a trace, but that doesn't help in this case.

Comment: You have permission do do "sp_who2" and "dbcc" but not run a trace?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to check out Adam Machanic's SP_WhoisActive it gives you all the info you need and it gives you the entire query in in xml so you can just click on it and see what is running.
http://whoisactive.com

Comment: I just tried `create proc #foo @a int as waitfor delay '01:00'`  then `exec #foo 1` I can't see the value of the parameters anywhere in the output.

Comment: This is a great tool, however, I still don't see parameters used to call the proc. I am calling like this:`exec sp_WhoIsActive @get_outer_command = 1`. It gives me two columns - sql_text and sql_command. sql_command gives me something like "MyDB.dbo.MyProc;1" where the 1 is a version number of the proc, not parameters sent in. sql_text gives me the statement in the proc that is executing. There are a lot of options for this call, am I missing one that would show the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I found this interesting code: `select dest.*
from  sys.dm_exec_requests as der
             cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text (der.sql_handle) as dest
where session_id = @spid`. Please try it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181929%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx

It looks like you can't do it without trace.
There few more posts with similar question: [Can parameterized queries be fully captured using DBCC INPUTBUFFER?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2053301/327165)

You can use DBCC INPUTBUFFER (spid) but only if sp is started from SSMS.

Look at this http://sqlblog.com/tags/Who+is+Active/default.aspx.
If you can't add this sp to your box, there will be code that can be helpful.

Edit: It will only show what statement of your sp is running, and not parameters.

Comment: Your most recent edit still only shows the `create proc` definition, not the parameters passed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the stored proc to log the parameters?  Perhaps insert into a table the parameters for diagnostics?